# Displaying captured details before Saving - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, phonegap

I need the user to preview records captured before inserting them. 
Any work arounds..

HTML.html

```
    <form id="view"  method="POST" class="formular">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text"  name="name"  id="name" /><br>
        <label>age</label>
        <input type="text"  name="age"  id="age" /><br>
        <label>place</label>
        <input type="text"  name="place"  id="place" />

        <button onclick="Preview()">Preview</button>
    </form >
```

JS.js

```
        function Preview()
            {
                var vName = document.getElementById("name").value;
                var vage = document.getElementById("age").value;
                var vplace = document.getElementById("place").value;

                var popup=window.open(view, 'Preview_records');
                popup.document.write('Name:' + vName + '<br /> Age:' + vage + '<br /> Place: ' + vplace + '<br />);
            }
```

When this window pops up, I want to have Proceed button and Cancel Button, where Proceed will take me to an insertion function and Cancel will drop back to edit form data.

Insertion function as

```
        function Insertion() {
            var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
            db.transaction(insertDT, errorZ, successY);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [SimpleModal](https://github.com/plasm/simplemodal) plugin for this requirement.

Once you download and load this library into your index.html, then use `MODAL` popup. Below is `MODAL INTEGRATION` code snippet:

```
 $("modal").addEvent("click", function(e){
    e.stop();
    var SM = new SimpleModal({"btn_ok":"Confirm button"});
        // Aggiunge Bottone Conferma
        SM.addButton("Confirm", "btn primary", function(){
            alert("Action confirm modal");
            this.hide();
        });
        // Aggiunge Bottone annulla
        SM.addButton("Cancel", "btn");
        SM.show({
          "model":"modal",
          "title":"Modal Window Title",
          "contents":"<p ><img style='text-align:center' src='assets/images/simpleModalSmallWhite.png' />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>"
        });
  })
```

In `contents` property add your `Preview()` function's content and you are done.

Here is link: https://github.com/plasm/simplemodal

Comment: @mountain, did you check my answer?

Comment: I tried but the window pops up when you click to enter records. Its detecting the form as an image

Comment: I got it now, had to change the trigger from click to submit. The only problem now is that my Jquery Mobile is conflicting with its layout hence it cant work.

Comment: @mountain, That's great it helped you. Not sure about conflicting issue. I think in your index.html order of loading scripts will need to change (not sure but try it). Your Jquery should be loaded at first.